# Could not retrieve Coveo for Sitecore license

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, coveo

Getting below Exception while going through the Control panel of `Sitecore`.

```
[LicenseNotFoundException: Could not retrieve Coveo for Sitecore license.]
   Coveo.SearchProvider.Licensing.Cloud.LicenseRetriever.GetLicense(Boolean p_ForceRetrieve) +274
   Coveo.SearchProvider.Licensing.LicenseManager.EnsureValidLicense() +77
   Coveo.SearchProvider.Licensing.LicenseManager.GetLicenseInformation() +57
   Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.Shell.Controls.ConfigureCoveoCloudOrganizationWizardFormPage.ReadFormValues() +483
   Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.Shell.Controls.ConfigurationFileUpdaterWizardFormPage`1.ActivePageChangingToNextPage() +108
   Coveo.SearchProvider.Applications.Shell.Controls.CoveoWizardForm.ActivePageChanging(String p_CurrentPageId, String& p_NextPageId) +215
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Pages.WizardForm.set_Active(String value) +106
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Button.DoClick(Message message) +60

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +221
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +231
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Component.HandleMessage(Message message) +195
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ClientEventCommand.SendEventMessage() +130
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ClientEventCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +16
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent() +78
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +801
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7479
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be [a known issue on Coveo](https://connect.coveo.com/s/article/2917), does it help? Or could be [similar as well](https://answers.coveo.com/questions/9157/error-reading-license-file-from-the-disk.html).

If none above helps - download [iLSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases) to see how/where license is looked for.